Stalks of the sheaf of continuous functions that vanish at $p$ vs stalks of the sheaf of continuous functions that vanish at a nbhd of $p$.
The following is from Evan Chen's napkin:

(Real functions vs. germs) Let $X$ be a space and let $\mathscr{F}$ be the sheaf of smooth functions. Take a section $f \in \mathscr{F}(U)$.

As a function, $f$ is just a choice of value $f(p) \in \Bbb R$ at every point $p$, subject to a local “smooth” condition.
Let’s now think of $f$ as a sequence of germs. At every point $p$ the germ $[f]_p \in \mathscr{F}_p$ gives us the value $f(p)$ as we described above. The germ packages even more data than this: from the germ $[f]_p$ alone we can for example compute $f'(p)$. Nonetheless we stretch the analogy and think of $f$ as a choice of germ $[f]_p \in \mathscr{F}_p$ at each point $p$.
Thus we can replace the notion of the value $f(p)$ with germ $[f]_p$. This is useful because in a general sheaf $\mathscr{F}$, the notion $s(p)$ is not defined while the notion $[s]_p$ is.


I'm reasonably new to sheaves and I can't really grasp the idea here. If I for example consider the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ of continuous function on $\Bbb R$ that vanish at the origin, is the stalk $\mathscr{F}_0= 0$? I tried to compare this with the sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ of functions that vanish at a neighborhood of the origin for which I do think that $\mathscr{G}_0 = 0$, but I do not really understand the differences between these two sheaves or rather than their stalks.
Do these two capture the same information or is there some notable difference between considering functions that vanish at a point with functions that vanish at a neighborhood of that point?

As a matter of notation, given a sheaf $\mathscr F$, $\mathscr F_p$ is the set (abelian group indeed) of all germs at $p$, and if $f\in\mathscr F(U)$ where $p\in U$, then $[f]_p\in\mathscr F_p$ is a particular germ.
If $\mathscr F$ is the sheaf of continuous functions on $\mathbb R$, then the stalk $\mathscr F_0$ is definitely not $0$ (more precisely, the trivial group), for many good reasons. For example, we do have a well-defined surjective homomorphism from $\mathscr F_0$ to $\mathbb R$ by $[f]_0\mapsto f(0)$ (you have to show this doesn't depend on $f$ by only on $[f]_0$). Intuitively, the constant functions $f\equiv r$ (as global sections) are distinct from each other when restricted to $0$ as germs, since they don't even agree with each other at $0$. However, the sitution is much more complicated than this: Even if $f(x)\equiv 0$ and $g(x)=x$ agree with each other at $x=0$, $[f]_0$ and $[g]_0$ are still different as germs, because no matter how small an open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ you choose, $f|_U$ and $g|_U$ are always different. Therefore the germs $[f]_p$ represent more information than $f(p)$ as a real number.
To make this more clear, let $\mathscr F$ be the sheaf of smooth functions on $\mathbb R$ (and open subsets), then we have $[f]_p\mapsto f^{(n)}(p)$ is a well-defined group homomorphism. In the case of analytic functions, these homomorphisms combined determine $[f]$ uniquely due to the power series expansion exists locally. However, in the case of sheaves of $C^{\infty}$-functions, even all these information are not sufficent to fully characterize $[f]_p$. From this, it should be clear that being $0$ at a precisely location $p$ is very different from being identically $0$ locally in a neighborhood of $p$. The former doesn't even capture the information about the derivative.
As for $\mathscr G$, I assume you mean the following:
$$\mathscr G(U) = \begin{cases} C(U, \mathbb R) & \text{ if } 0\not\in U \\ \{f\in C(U, \mathbb R): \exists \text{ open } V\subset U, f|_{V}\equiv 0 \} & \text{ if }0\in U \end{cases}$$
In this case, yeah, $\mathscr G_0$ is trivial. Intuitively, this simply cuts any complexities around $0$ out of the picture.
In differential and algebraic geometry, we often have to face structure sheaves that are not consisting of functions. In those cases, given a section $s$, $s(p)$ is not even defined. Schemes are perfect examples, but if you haven't studied algebraic geometry yet, here is one concrete example: Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, and $\Lambda^r(M)$ be the sheaf of smooth differential $r$-forms on $M$, then given a differential form $\omega$, you cannot evaluate it at any specific point. What is $dx$ evaluated at $0$ (when $M=
\mathbb R$)? This is simply not defined, but you can define $[dx]_0$. BTW, for more on Structure Sheaves Versus Sheaves of Functions, you may have a look at Gelfand & Manin (Section II.4).

Thanks alot! And $\mathscr{G}$ really is a sheaf since being zero in a open neighborhood of $0$ is a local property? @just-a-user

@Sehat Yes. It can also be directly checked that there is no problem to restrict and glue within this class of functions.
